# React Native FlatList keyboardShouldPersistTaps not persisting

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I have a very frustrating situation. Trying to get keyboard to disappear and detect onPress event handler in child row.

Here is what my code looks like:

```
  _renderRow = (prediction) => {
    return (
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {
        Keyboard.dismiss();
        this.setState({ location: prediction.description });
      }}>
        <View style={styles.listItemContainer}>
          <Text>{prediction.description}</Text>
        </View>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    )
  }

  render() {
    return (
    <View style={styles.wrapper}>
      {/* style={[this.state.predictions.length > 0 ? styles.searchContainerSuggest : styles.searchContainer]} */}
      <View style={styles.searchContainerSuggest}>
        <View style={{paddingLeft: 10, height: 45, display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'center'}}>
          <TextInput
            placeholder="Enter location"
            value={this.state.location}
            onChangeText={location => this.onChangeLocation(location)}
            style={styles.textInput}
          />
        </View>
        {this.state.predictions.length && this.state.location !== '' ?
          <FlatList
            keyboardShouldPersistTaps={'handled'}
            refreshing={!this.state.loaded}
            initialNumToRender={10}
            enableEmptySections={true}
            data={this.state.predictions}
            keyExtractor={(_, index) => index.toString()}
            renderItem={ ({item: prediction}) => this._renderRow(prediction) } />
            : null}
      </View>
    </View>
    );
  }
```

I probably need a helping hand or two with regards to how to debug this issue.

Looked up several examples on how to deal with hiding the keyboard and allowing a particular selection to be pressed at the same time.

I thought that keyboardShouldPersistTaps would allow for the child selection to be selected. Upon selection, the onPress event handler will trigger and that will be where I call Keyboard.dismiss() to hide the keyboard. Does not seem to work.

Answer (score 5):

In my case, besides adding `keyboardShouldPersistTabs='handled'` to the `FlatList` in question, it was also needed to add `keyboardShouldPersistTabs='handled'` and `nestedScrollEnabled={true}` to a parent `ScrollView` like 2 levels above, wrapping the `FlatList` I intended to get this behavior with. Check out [this issue](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/28860#issuecomment-630457205) in `react-native` repo for more info.

Answer (score 4):

For anyone who is running into the same problem as me. Check whether your FlatList or ScrollView is nested in another FlatList or ScrollView.

If yes, then add

```
keyboardShouldPersistTaps='handled'
```

to the element as a props as well.

Answer (score 0):

add keyboardDismissMode="none" to FlatList

Comment: added it as a line above keyboardShouldPersistTap, didn't work